# Django DateTimeField with auto_now_add asks for default

Tags: django

I have this field in my model `created_at = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True )`

When I try to make migrations I get an error:

```
You are trying to add the field 'created_at' with 'auto_now_add=True' to user wi
thout a default; the database needs something to populate existing rows.

 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

I tried to set the default value but it says `default` and `auto_now_add` are mutually exclusive. Of course I could just use default without `auto_now_add` but I want to know why this error pops up. Did I miss something?

Comment: This is because you have already some rows without `created_at` value.

Comment: @shafik yes indeed. So what is the correct solution if I want to use `auto_now_add`?

Comment: You may choose the 1st option when running migrations then give the value `timezone.now()`. Then existing rows are populated with the current timestamp.

Comment: @shafik that did it. If you want to sum it up as an answer below, I will accept it the proper way

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have already some rows without `created_at` value.
But when you added following field and run migration

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add = True)
```

It expects the existing row has `created_at` value. So, It warns you at the time of migrations.

To solve this problem.
You can choose the 1st option which says `Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)`.
By choosing the 1st option you are asking for value. Here you can enter `timezone.now()`. It will populate existing rows with the current timestamp.

Comment: Only the first option worked for me. Changes to the model gave me this error: `The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.`

Comment: Oh Ok. I forgot to mention this. It's better to follow the 1st option.

Comment: Django documents state that using auto_add_now=True will also set Blank=True, so why does it need to set values on rows that existed previously when Blank=True?

Comment: @MattWarren `blank=True` matters only for form validation, not validation when saving models.

Answer (score 9):

**Delete the migration file in app and you can makemigrtion process at the time no error raises**, It raises due to the reason of previously created time object.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a sqlite database you can omit it and again make it,
or you can write null=True as an argument for your DateTimeFeild()
i suggest you the second one that i have done before

Answer (score 1):

you can create two migrations,

- the first one sets a default value,
- the second remove the default and add the auto_now_add

Answer (score 0):

That is because auto_now_add = True make django determine every instance of the model should have a value instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

when migrating use:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb