# django table onlineshop_product has no column named name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I work on an online shopping website project with the help of Django. and I'm a beginner in Django The following code provides a table of my database. It helps to add a product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Shows me an error in the browser. This error shows me when I add a product inside the admin panel. It helps to add a product but when I add the product the following error occurs.

> OperationalError at /admin/onlineshop/product/add/
>
> table onlineshop_product has no column named name

When I did migration using the command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It shows:

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
> contenttypes, onlineshop, sessions Running migrations:   No migrations
> to apply.   Your models in app(s): 'onlineshop' have changes that are
> not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.   Run
> 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run
> 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

> It is impossible to add the field 'created' with 'auto_now_add=True'
> to product without providing a default. This is because the database
> needs something to populate existing rows.
>
> 1. Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing
>    rows
> 2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py. Select
>    an option:

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known issue, refer [`here`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30337?msclkid=8f9f319dcec611ec85daeda07203f996)<sup>[django-doc]</sup> for this, it will be easy if you choose 1st option.

Choose 1st option:

Then, you will be shown something like this in your shell:

```
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
You can accept the default 'timezone.now' by pressing 'Enter' or you can provide another value.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
[default: timezone.now] >>>
```

Here, simply press Enter the field will be added to migration and your work is done then simply run `migrate` command. You can also check it in `migration` file.

Migration file

```
operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            ....
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now),
        )
    ]
```

#### Edit:

Try this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='any_name')
```

Then run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: It will show again     `It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'name' to product without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option: migrate
Please select a valid option:`

Comment: Yes, press 1 and then press Enter it will make `alter` operation on table.

Comment: @pycoder Listen, i haven't looked clearly, it is because you haven't give `default` in your `name` field in model, it is not about `created` field, add `default='some_name'` in your `name` field, then it will resolve.

Comment: @pycoder I edited my answer for this, see it.

Comment: no, i am saying press 1 and then press enter not ctrl+c, it will exit the prompt for 'created' field. which problem do you exactly facing now?

Comment: I'm a beginner in Django   `name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='name')`  True or not??

Comment: If you know sql, `default` means default value, set it to `pycoder`, then the default name, when user does not give any name while adding records, then it will automatically set pycoder. Its true, but avoid `default='name'` set something else which will be meaningful, also it can clash with your field itself.

Comment: Yeah, I know but how to access SQL??? I have one db.sqlite3 file

Comment: @pycoder So, what you want now? Which problem do you have now?

Comment: `OperationalError at /admin/onlineshop/product/add/`




`table onlineshop_product has no column named name`


this is the error when I go admin panel and add product Shows me an error in the browser.

Comment: Hello @pycoder **default** is used if there is no value provided by user then it will use default value because you've created your column without setting **`null=True`** which means it will raise **sql** error if  it's set to empty so for this reason either you set **`null=True`** to your name field or you can specify default value.

Comment: `from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)



    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
        verbose_name='category'
        verbose_name_plural='categories'



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`

Comment: Read this comment at least two or three times, do exactly it, set `name=models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='avatar')`, then run makemigrations and migrate, it will resolve error related to `name` field of your model, and for `created` I have already mentioned.

Comment: @pycoder No need to make changes in the view.

Comment: *`OperationalError at /admin/onlineshop/product/add/ table onlineshop_product has no column named name`* - this error occured because you changed your name filed and you didn't run **makemigrations** & **migrations** command

Comment: ok....I run,  `python manage.py makemigrations` ,  1) Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py. Then choose option1,  Then simply press Enter, and Again it will appear  1) Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

Comment: @pycoder That was for `created` field, Here, you have to manually set `default` in `name` field, then run migration commands.

Comment: `name=models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='avatar')`  manually set `default` and run makemigration and migration but after it will appear It is impossible to add the field 'created' with 'auto_now_add=True' to product without providing a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.

 `1) Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option:`

Comment: @pycoder yes , select on 1st option now, and then simply enter it will make `alter` operation on table. then run migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Change your **`Product(...)`** class like this:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Product(models.Model):
    # ... all other fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, default='Name not provided')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

and run these commands in sequence:

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name # app name is optional parameter if you have app then provide app name
python manage.py migrate
```

Although settings **`null = True`** is bad idea but this will solve your problem for now but if you want to fix this issue you can  follow this [post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56310408/14457833).

### Update

If above solution is not working or facing some issue then do like this:

> **Note** : In this approach you've to delete you database (sqlite).

#### Step - 1

Delete **`__pycache__`** & **`migrations`** folders from all of your apps 


[image]

#### Step - 2

Delete **db.sqlite3**


[image]

#### Step - 3

Run makemigrations & migrate commands as mentioned above.

Comment: `ERRORS:
onlineshop.Product.created: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.
onlineshop.Product.updated: (fields.E160) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.`
Error or not??

Comment: @pycoder Yes, it is because it by default refers to `django.utils.timezone.now`, only providing default to your `name` field and for your `created` field, selecting at first option will resolve the problem or else anything won't.

Comment: Hello @pycoder check I've edited my answer changed `created`  & `updated` fields.

Comment: Try to refresh your page I've changed my answer

Comment: `Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, onlineshop, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'onlineshop' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

Comment: Please run `makemigrations` first then run `migrate` command

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations`   It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'price' to product without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value as valid Python.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari That's also right, but I haven't recommended since he is already a beginner, if he by mistake forget to delete any of migration files, then he cannot do anything further :).